# AWS localstack denies HTTP requests from a running service on the same machine

Tags: docker, localstack

I have some application that is run on my local machine with docker.
In the docker-compose.yml file there is:

```
services:
...
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - "4567-4583:4567-4583"
    environment:
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - SERVICES=sqs,dynamodb,s3
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "/private${TMPDIR}:/tmp/localstack"
    networks:
      - webhooks
```

and I launch the docker application by running the command

```
docker-compose up
```

When I run the main service of the application, it is supposed to call the pseudo DynamoDB database that runs within the docker, and then I get the error:

```
[info] 20:24:47.106 [undefined|…pool-9-thread-1] W c.r.webhooks.services.aws.Dynamo$    - Retrying AWS request; retry #0 []
[info] com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: The target server failed to respond
[info]  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1136)
[info]  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1082)
[info]  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:745)
[info]  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:719)
[info]  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:701)
[info]  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:669)
[info]  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:651)
[info]  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:515)
[info]  at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.doInvoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2925)
[info]  at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2901)
[info]  at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.executeDescribeTable(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1515)
[info]  at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient$13.call(AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient.java:840)
[info]  at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient$13.call(AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient.java:834)
[info]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[info]  at com.riskified.webhooks.utils.monitoring.KamonAwsExecutorFactory$ContextRunnable.run(KamonAwsExecutorFactory.scala:17)
[info]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
[info]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
```

It look that my main app cannot connect to the DynamoDB in localstack, although that I have started it before I launched my server. If I have to make a bet, I'll say that the container that holds localstack blocks it from getting HTTP request from outside the container.

Do you have any idea why I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to access the DynamoDB service (which URL)? and from where?

E.g. when you are trying to reach S3 or DynamoDB from within a lambda function you need the URL to be `http://${process.env.LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME}:EDGE_PORT` according to docs;

> Additionally, the following read-only environment variables are
> available:
>
> LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME: Name of the host where LocalStack services are
> available. Use this hostname as endpoint (e.g.,
> http://${LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME}:4566) in order to access the services
> from within your Lambda functions (e.g., to store an item to DynamoDB
> or S3 from a Lambda).